# Insert contents of a text file into the Oracle CLOB

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-studio-2015, clob

I'm trying to insert whole text contents of file.txt into a CLOB column!

```
Connection^ DB = gcnew Connection();
OracleConnection^ Ocnn=DB->getOracleConnectionObject();
int number = 0;

try {
    // here >>
    OracleCommand^ c = gcnew OracleCommand("INSERT INTO PANDA.PAGE(SITE_ID, URL, SOURCE) VALUES('40', 'www.site.com', Read_Whole_File('C://Users/farmehr/Desktop/', 'file.txt'))", Ocnn);
    number = c->ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (Exception^ eOra) {
    Console::WriteLine(eOra->Message + "Exception Caught");
    throw eOra;
}
```

I want to know is there any way to insert file directly to the data base? ( A function like Read_Whole_File() in the code )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to be able to insert a file into a clob first I had to make a procedure in SQLPLUS! SOURCE is my clob file and TEMP_CLOB is a predefined directory.

[image]

Next in my code I had to run this procedure:

[image]

Using code:

[image]

Result:

[image]

-Keep this in mind that for making and running procedures you have to login AS SYSDBA.( Change oracleClient.dll to OracleManagedAcess.dll if you're using C or .NET)